# scrollTop addclass makes a jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I am pretty much a newbie in coding, and i am currently working on a company as part of my studies.
They gave me an html and css file to edit, i had to make an image appear and disappear depending on the distance scrolled. I managed to make the class disappear after getting to a concrete distance from the top, but it makes a weird jump. The code isn't mine, i just edited some things so if any information is missing please tell me so i can add it.

The HTML goes like this:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){ 

var nav = $('#feedback_form'); 

$(window).scroll(function () { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 445 && $(this).scrollTop() < 1289 ) { 
        nav.addClass("f-nav");
    } else { 
        nav.removeClass("f-nav");
    } 

});
```

And the "f-nav" class it's referring to in the css is this one:

```
.f-nav {
z-index: 9998!important;
position: fixed!important;
top: 0; 

-webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1; /* Firefox */
-ms-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1; /* Internet Explorer */
-o-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1; /* Opera */
animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;

-webkit-animation-duration:2s;
-moz-animation-duration:2s;
-ms-animation-duration:2s;
-o-animation-duration:2s;
animation-duration:2s;

}
```

The addClass also makes a jump but it's less noticeable.
Like i said im pretty new to this so i don't know where the problem could be coming from.

Here's a gyazo to the problem:

https://gyazo.com/9b3e0a910c095fa3b180b9501eed9981

Comment: Use `position:sticky`

Comment: I changed the position to sticky from fixed, but the jump is still there when the class gets removed.

Comment: You can provide a demo to reproduce the problem first.

Comment: I'm not quite allowed to share too much of the HTML or CSS because it's from my company, not mine. That's why i wanted to know if, with the data that i shared, someone could find the cause of the problem or a solution. Also I don't know enough as to make a demo since i'm not sure of which codelines are important and which aren't.

Comment: Also i just realized that you can't see the faces before they appear on the scroll, while using my code the faces are there and they follow the scroll once gone under them. The only problem in my code is the little jumps it makes for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it'll work

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 445 || $("html").scrollTop() > 289) {
  $("#feedback_form").fadeIn();
} else {
  $("#feedback_form").fadeOut();
};
```

Are you sure that in your code, $(this) is declared?
Accept if my code work, or let me know if there is anything. I can help you.

Comment: If i use that instead of what i have, it does dissimulate the jump (thanks!), but then the images don't follow throught the scroll. My objective is that the faces follow the scroll until a certain point and then disappear (As shown in the gyazo). About the $(this), where do i look if it's declared? Is it supposed to have a class in the css?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to write code here I have to make another answer:
About the $(this), you have to know what is $(this). For example:

```
$(".ex").click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("example");
})
```

$(this) above mean $(".ex).

And the images don't follow throught the scroll I think it's because of z-index (maybe).

So try this:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 445 || $("html").scrollTop() < 1289) {
  $("#feedback_form").fadeIn().addClass("myClass");
} else {
  $("#feedback_form").fadeOut();
};
```

with

```
.myClass{
   position: fixed; /*add !important if you need*/
   z-index: 9999; /*add !important if you need*/
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: With the code you wrote it does appear smoothly, but it doesn't disappear when you get to the end of the page. Also it appears in the middle of the page and smaller than it should. But the main problem is kind of solved.

Comment: Actually, I did something wrong at:
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 445 || $("html").scrollTop() > 289) and I fixed it: if ($(window).scrollTop() > 445 || $("html").scrollTop() < 1289).
Upvote and accept the answer if it helps you. Thank you

Comment: In fact, when i use "< 1289" instead of "> 289" it doesn't disappear at all. Also i still don't know why it's in the middle of the apge or why it's smaller than it should. Does it have to do with the css?

Comment: Maybe it because your web's height is smaller than 1289, so change the number "1289" to a smaller number. And it's smaller than it should because of the css position: fixed, use can add: width: 100% (or a number) to class .myClass

Comment: It still makes the same, i'm going to keep trying with different values or mixing your code with mine, if it works I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Do you have a virtual host or something that I can check it out?

Comment: Not quite, but i will ask tomorrow if I'm allowed to post the full HTML or a working demo in jsfiddle.